# php - how to use readdfile to not force a download

Tags: php, stream, download

Is there a way to use php readdfile function to allow browsers to stream media files, such as an mp3 file?
I currently have a download system where readdfile is used because the file downloads are not stored in a public directory, however, I would like my users to be able to stream these files with there browser. At the moment, it forces them to download.
I have used the example from php.net.
thanks,
josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what the files are, and what you mean by "stream". The proper definition, in this context, is to send out enough of a large audio or video file that it can be played clientside without having to have received the entire file. Also, most streaming service allow the user to 'seek' to any given position in the video and have the stream restart at that point, again so that the user does not have to download the whole file.

The above requires specialized streaming server software.

However, I get the feeling that you may simply want the browser to open the file instead of prompting the user to save it. This requires you to set the `Content-Type:` header with the proper [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) to the client via the [`header()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.